# Hadoop Daemon Log

Tags: logging, hadoop, daemon

This probably sounds like a really simple question, but does anyone know how to access the daemon logs on hadoop? My ResourceManager is not connecting so I am trying to locate the error.

I did some research online and found `hadoop-<user-running-hadoop>-<daemon>-<hostname>.log` but this didn't work for me. I suspect I entered my hostname incorrectly; my hostname is "Macintosh.local" but this had no effect. Or maybe I'm supposed to be in a specific directory when I run this command?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When running a hadoop daemon, **HADOOP_HOME** environmental variable should be set. You should check the logs in **$HADOOP_HOME/logs** directory to identify the issue.